# Passing CPLEX Parameters to CVXPY

Tags: python, cplex, cvxpy

How do i pass tolerances and other parameters through CVXPY when using the CPLEX solver?

```
from cvxpy import Problem, Minimize
from cvxpy.settings import CPLEX
costs = ...
constraints = ...
prob = Problem(Minimize(costs), constraints)
prob.solve(solver=CPLEX, ...)
```

I see a page of [CPLEX Parameters](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SS9UKU_12.4.0/com.ibm.cplex.zos.help/Parameters/topics/introListAlpha.html) though it is unclear which ones apply to my quadratic problem.   Also, the [CVXPY documentation](https://www.cvxpy.org/tutorial/advanced/index.html) has pass through options for other solvers but not CPLEX.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will change in the future (see [this](https://github.com/cvxgrp/cvxpy/pull/506) pull request), but with cvxpy 1.0.6, you can do the following (NOTE: this is undocumented behavior; see below for more):

```
prob.solve(solver=CPLEX, advance=0)
```

The `advance=0` will turn "off" the [advanced start switch](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.8.0/ilog.odms.cplex.help/CPLEX/Parameters/topics/AdvInd.html) parameter. So, if the parameter name is `parameters.advance` in the CPLEX Python API, you would pass in the part after `parameters.` (i.e., `advance`) and the value as a keyword argument. Any extra keyword arguments that are passed to the [solve](https://www.cvxpy.org/tutorial/advanced/index.html#solve-method-options) method are interpreted this way. For debugging, you should probably set `verbose=True` (one of the standard keyword arguments to `solve`) to turn on the engine log; the parameter settings will be displayed at the top of the log.

This behavior was not documented for good reason. It doesn't allow you to set parameters like [data consistency checking and modeling assistance](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.8.0/ilog.odms.cplex.help/CPLEX/Parameters/topics/DataCheck.html). That parameter name in the CPLEX Python API is `parameters.read.datacheck` but `read.datacheck` cannot be used as a keyword argument in Python (it would result in a syntax error).

As a workaround, consider using the `ILOG_CPLEX_PARAMETER_FILE` environment variable, which is documented [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.8.0/ilog.odms.cplex.help/CPLEX/UsrMan/topics/progr_consid/environmentVariables.html).

---

**EDIT**: the workaround above is no longer necessary with cvxpy 1.0.8. That is, you should be able to set all of the parameters now regardless of where they are in the parameter hierarchy. You need to use the optional `cplex_params` argument, though. It's nice to combine this with `verbose=True` so that you can see the parameter settings in the engine log. For example:

```
prob.solve(solver=cvxpy.CPLEX,
           verbose=True,
           cplex_params={"mip.tolerances.absmipgap": 1e-07, 
                         "benders.strategy": 3})
```

Comment: So if I understand correctly since Tolerance is buried one level down I'll need to use the parameter file to lower the tolerance.

Comment: @rhaskett: I'm not sure which tolerance parameter you're referring to (there are many), but yes, that sounds correct. For example, this is true for the [absolute MIP gap tolerance](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.8.0/ilog.odms.cplex.help/CPLEX/Parameters/topics/EpAGap.html).