# How to specify GUROBI environment parameters in cvxpy

Tags: python, gurobi, cvxpy

How can I pass the [environment parameters](https://www.gurobi.com/documentation/9.1/refman/parameters.html), like the time_limit or optimality gap for GUROBI solver in cvxpy?

Here is what I tried according to [cvxpy documentation](https://www.cvxpy.org/tutorial/advanced/index.html#solve-method-options) which gives this error: `AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute '_cenv'`

```py
import cvxpy as cp
problem = cp.Problem(objective, constraints)

...

env = {
    "time_limit": 1
}
problem.solve(solver='GUROBI', env=env)
```

The process for [CPLEX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51772382/passing-cplex-parameters-to-cvxpy) is more straightforward I guess. I couldn't find a solution for GUROBI though.

Answer (score 2):

GUROBI has an Env method which can be accessed in python with `gurobipy`. Env shouldn't be a dict.

Here is what I did:

```py
import gurobipy
import cvxpy as cp
problem = cp.Problem(objective, constraints)

...

env = gurobipy.Env()
env.setParam('TimeLimit', 10) # in seconds

problem.solve(solver='GUROBI', env=env)
```

Comment: This worked for me. I also found that using gurobipy directly was not only faster than cvxpy because there was no problem reduction step, but that gurobipy seemed to find solutions faster; this hints that perhaps cvxpy is obfuscating a problem that gurobipy was otherwise able to analyze better on its own.